# closure of the integers under +, -, *, /, ^

Tags: field-theory

I'm interested in the set $S$ of complex numbers that can be characterized as follows:

1. $\mathbb{Z}$ is in $S$.
2. If $a$ and $b$ are in $S$ then $a+b$, $a-b$ and $a*b$ are in $S$.
3. If $a$ and $b$ are in $S$ and $b\neq{0}$ then $a/b$ is in $S$.
4. If $a$ and $b$ are in $S$ and not both $0$ then $a^b$ is in $S$.

This set contains some numbers that are not algebraic, like $2^\sqrt{2}$ (by the Gelfond–Schneider theorem). It contains all algebraic numbers that are roots of solvable polynomials. Whether it contains the remaining algebraic numbers is not obvious to me.

My question is, has this set been studied much? Does it have a name, or belong to any particular field of math? I'm curious about whether, for example, denominator rationalization is always possible for these numbers, as it is with algebraic numbers, but I don't know where to start looking. I suppose there is also a question of whether it's even well-defined. I know exponentiation by complex numbers gets messy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field

Comment: @dcheuk The idea is that S is the smallest exponential field that contains the rationals and some particular exponential map, right? Should it be obvious how to define that map? Some way or constructing S from Q like Q is constructed as the field of fractions of Z.

Comment: There must be a countable subfield of $\Bbb R$ that satisfies this.  Start with $\Bbb Z$ and close under the operations.

Comment: @dcheuk That's not entirely right. An exponential field has a single exponential map. We want our field to have an exponential map for each element in the field. Specifically, for each $a\in S$ (possibly with single exceptions, like $1$ and $0$), we have an exponential map $E_a$ such that $E_a(1)=a$.

Comment: @RossMillikan It's not a subset of the reals because it contains i, but noted that it must be countable.

Comment: You didn't say so, Alex, but I assume you want $S$ to be the smallest subset of the complex numbers with the given properties.

Comment: Not the same, but a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744105/the-smallest-class-of-numbers-closed-under-addition-multiplication-and-exponen

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @AlexKindel:  you are right, $i$ is in there.